# Capturing percentage of occurence

Tags: sql, r, ms-access

I would like to capture the data that shows if item 1 has left a facility, then the percentage of time that item 2 has left with item 1 is x%. I'm not certain if Access SQL has the capability to capture this question. I would like to know if this is even possible to do in SQL or if I have graduated from Access to something else, potentially R and Python?

What I have thus far:

Thanks to a poster from yesterday, I was able to group items together based on if they have ever left together at any time with the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.TK, b.TK
FROM access3 a JOIN access3 b ON a.DocumentNo = b.DocumentNo
WHERE NOT a.TK=b.TK
ORDER BY a.TK,b.TK
```

This gives the following output sample:

```
TK15535 TK16644
TK15535 TK17566
TK15535 TK18306
TK15535 TK18747
TK15535 TK19183
TK15535 TK19505
TK15535 TK23247
TK15539 TK15535
TK15539 TK16644
TK16330 TK11297
TK16330 TK11300
TK16330 TK11301
TK16330 TK11309
TK16330 TK11320
TK16330 TK12081
TK16330 TK12233
TK16330 TK12395
TK16330 TK12405
```

Again, this says that if a TK# has ever occurred in a document no. with another TK#, then it appears in the query.

Here is some sample data to get an idea of what I'm working with:

```
Document No.    TK# Posting Date    Quantity    Date
SSPT254937  TK24006 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254937  TK24006 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254937  TK27511 3/7/2019    4   19-03
SSPT254937  TK27508 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254955  TK19183 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254955  TK23247 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254956  21635   3/7/2019    150 19-03
SSPT254957  TK14813 3/7/2019    3   19-03
SSPT254962  TK16737 3/7/2019    4   19-03
SSPT254962  TK18008 3/7/2019    4   19-03
SSPT254977  TK26041 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254977  TK26042 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254977  TK22483 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254977  TK22481 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254979  TK20454 3/7/2019    2   19-03
SSPT254980  TK17715 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254982  TK29195 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254982  TK29078 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254982  TK29199 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK24784 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK25284 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK28267 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK28268 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK20098 3/7/2019    2   19-03
SSPT254983  TK21407 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254983  TK25632 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254984  TK15012 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254988  TK20003 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254988  TK18816 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254989  TK14094 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254989  TK21180 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254991  TK11309 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254991  TK20245 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT254991  TK16918 3/7/2019    1   19-03
SSPT266212  29001   5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266235  TK13958 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266236  TK16330 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266236  TK16332 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266236  TK16331 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266236  TK16737 5/20/2019   4   19-05
SSPT266236  TK18008 5/20/2019   4   19-05
SSPT266238  TK16343 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266238  TK16345 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266239  TK18815 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266239  TK15484 5/20/2019   2   19-05
SSPT266240  TK22951 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266240  TK22951 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266240  TK22951 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266240  TK22951 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK25676 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK25676 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK27435 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK27741 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK27914 5/20/2019   1   19-05
SSPT266242  TK25067 5/20/2019   1   19-05
```

What I've tried thus far:

I went back into Excel to see if there's some clever way I can extract this percentage I'm looking for by looking at the Pivot Table. It doesn't give a nice way of seeing the data to extrapolate a percentage of shipping, would have to do by hand calculation for all 600+ items if I were to use a pivot table.

The second idea was to use a SQL query to see if it would show frequency, but I don't see any type of function that would give me that.
For reference, I'm looking here to see if a function exists: http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_functions.asp.html

I suppose what I would like to see is something like

```
TK16330        TK16331      .85
TK16330        TK16332      .53
TK16330        TK16343      .92
etc
```

Is this even possible with SQL, or have I graduated?

Comment: Are item1 and item2 variables? or is a % with all ItemX vs ItemY? or is Item1 the variable and ItemY the rest of items?

Comment: I suppose I'm not quite sure what you're asking, I apologize. What I'd like to know is if item 1 (say TK16330) has left a facility, what items has it left with, and also what percentage of the time did it leave with TK16330?

Which now that I think about it, the first item is the independent variable, and the others are variable.

Comment: I mean do you have `Item1 = TK163301` or is all TK vs all TK

Comment: @bosois . . . You mention times and items.  Your code mentions documents and tks.  I'm confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think Items are TK... Documents are Orders

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, items are TK. Documents are Orders. Sorry about that!
Secondarily, it's TK vs all TK. I used TK16330 as an example.

Comment: @bosois: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then explain more briefly what you want and add the additional infos from your comments to question!

Comment: For document `SSPT255279` you have `2xTK20066` and `2xTK18311` is that correct?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In this sample space, that's correct.Ah, that's a mistake. There are no repeats in Document No AND TK#.
Will update sample space.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza to clarify that last point because that reads confusingly still I think:

You have Document 1. Tk1, TK 2 have left together at x and y quantities. Document 2 has TK1 at z quantity. Document 3 has TK1 and TK 2 at a and b quantities. The question is: what is the percentage of quantity and times that TK 1 and TK 2 have left together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the concurrence of all pairs by joining in the appropriate rows and aggregating.

The following works assuming that there are no duplicates in the table.

```
select tk, tk2, count(*), count(a2.tk) / count(*) as ratio
from ((select distinct a.TK, a2.TK as tk2
       from access3 as a inner join
            access3 as a2 
            on a.DocumentNo = a2.DocumentNo
       where a.TK <> a2.TK
      ) tt left join
      access3 as a
      on a.tk = tt.tk
     ) left join
     access3 as a2
     on a2.tk = tt.tk2 and a2.documentNo = a.documentNo
group by tk, tk2;
```

As for choice of tools, almost any database *other than MS Access* is going to make this easier.  MS Access, for instance, does not support:

- Window functions
- CTEs
- Count distinct
- Inequalities in outer join conditions

Those are four things that might be useful for this problem.  There are a bunch of other things as well.

Comment: How does one skirt around the problem of there being repeat info? The Document No. won't be repeated, but TK#s will definitely have repeats.

Comment: Gordon can you check the query. Im getting wrong values. For example 18311 appear only twice and on the query there is one with 4 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUyL9Tht5aBEfyQkUJr3GS/0

Comment: You didn't mention Quantity was a factor on calculation, and question doesn't show  anything about it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm still getting this wrong. In the end, it doesn't matter if they have quantity attached to it. I just want to know the percentage of times they have shipped out together in total. It could be that TK1 has shipped out on its own and also that it has shipped out with TK2. Want to know percentage of times it has shipped out with TK2.

Comment: This solution appears to work actually now that I tried it out with a not terrible sample space. My sample space had TK20006 and TK18816. TK20006 shipped out twice with 18816, so it has a 100% ratio. However 18816 only went out twice with it, but went out 2 more times with other items. So It correctly calculated 50%. Thank you very much Gordon!!!!!